# Doesn't the doppler effect prove that light is a wave?

Tags: visible-light

According to me doppler effect can only be applied to waves and not particles, as we apply doppler effect on light it proves it having wave nature and not particle nature.

Comment: We'll need a better source than just you that the Doppler effect can only apply to waves.

Comment: If you run away from a machine gunner, the frequency of bullet wounds will be red-shifted.

Comment: Whoever said that light was not a wave?

Comment: It's worth noting that the Doppler behavior of light is different from the Doppler behavior of waves propagating in media; different formulae and different logic to explain them. Using the audio Doppler shift as a model for light can lead you into error.

Answer (score 4):

The Doppler effect proves that light can **behave like a wave** under some circumstances, but it doesn't prove that light **is a wave**.

Likewise the photoelectric effect proves that light can behave like a particle under some circumstances, but doesn't prove that light is a particle.

Light is described by quantum field theory, specifically quantum electrodynamics, and it is neither a wave nor a particle. However it can behave like either. As a general rule light behaves like a wave when we examine its propagation properties and it behaves like a particle when it is exchanging energy with something. This also applies to all the fundamental particles, not just light.

Comment: Also, the Doppler Effect was proposed a few years *after* we discovered that light behaves as a wave. So when the Doppler shift was first used, we already knew light would behave like a wave and didn't need Doppler to see that.

Comment: One should rather say that it behaves like a quantum, which is not the same as a particle. Quanta can behave particle-ish, but only in a medium they interact with weakly.

Comment: But if light exhibits doppler effect then it should prove that it cannot behave like particles (assuming doppler effect to be applicable only to waves)

Comment: @ClarkDale it's called particle-wave duality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality). Light behaves like particles **and** waves so theories that apply to either, will also apply to light depending on how you're analyzing it.

Comment: @MBarbosa I know about the duality that is the reason I thought that doppler effect shows that light behaves like a wave and not like a particle. Now I can see that it depends on how we are analyzing it. Its the observer then who "selects" the wave or particle nature of light?

Comment: @ClarkDale if you say "behaves like a wave and not like a particle" that is not duality, that is singularity. Duality means it acts like both simultaneously. In fact, it truly "acts" like neither, because waves and particles are just models that we have, so light will not adapt based on what model you are using it will just keep being light. But in short, yes the observer chooses how to analyze it.